# Wordpress theme requirements

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Recently I started thinking about building pro themes and selling them over themeforest. Themes would be intended for developers, so i wouldn't use page builders and similar plugins, they will be build for best performance and fast content display. I have couple of questions before I start, maybe you can help me?

I don't know which functionalities should theme have, should it be multipurpose or purpose based, which is better?
Are there any rules about which options and sections theme must have to be allowed to sell on themeforest?
Is there any boilerplate for wordpress theme files and/or documentation?
Should i build from the ground up or use some theme framework?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it appears to be a question to ask on themeforest website / forums  - and further more - [the info is readily available and easily found](https://help.market.envato.com/hc/en-us/articles/202822450-WordPress-Theme-Submission-Requirements) on that specific website. it would also might be more appropriate for http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use frameworks. There are many frameworks out there like genesis, Artisteer, TemplateToaster, headways. Choose the best that fits you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go with Themeforest, firstly make sure your theme has an aesthetic design :) You can check out some of its popular themes to get the idea.

Also provide many options, but try not to make them very confusing for users. E.g. separate them to sections/directories.

And I believe they have coding standards, you might want to check that as well.
Hope that helped :)

Answer (score 0):

Regarding boilerplates for WordPress themes: Check out [_s by Automattic](http://underscores.me) (the people behind WordPress.com)

It's well documented, very minimal and great for starting a new theme from scratch. It also teaches you some good coding standards.

You should also check out the [Theme Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/) by WordPress for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Is it smart to use angular.js for frontend, or is that a bit futuristic for standards theme development?